# on tab click run oncreate() method of corresponding class android

Tags: android

i have 4 tabs in my same view i want to that when i chnge the tabs and load it again it always run its oncreate() method of corresponding class...each time when i change the tab it runs it's called class.i have a problem with this bcoz tab click event load its view in first time when i click on it then again if i changing the tab it's only load it again not run its oncreate() method so how to over come this problem ...

i had also used....

```
intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, keywordxmlparsing.class);
spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Activity2").setIndicator("keyword search...").setContent(intent1);
tabHost.addTab(spec1); 

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String label) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(label == "Activity2") {

           Variables.a=2;


    }
    try{
    if(label == "Activity4") {


    }
```

so on tab change how to run its corresponding class again when i push tab again???
thanks in adv. to all my response-rs..

Answer (score 0):

put your code in OnResume() methods,it may help you

Comment: hi..riser actually i am performing some task on another tab click click event and when i change the tab the second tab click result depend on the first tab click result and on second tab click i load data asynchronously from server each time when click happen.and for loading the data i have url which is in oncreate() method so each time i have to use that url and read it again so now can u explain it pls

Comment: hey riser how to release view's old loaded content on tab click??when i click second time

Comment: bcoz when i load data second time means it run on resume() method but first loaded data are ther so giving array i ndex out of bound exception...so how to over come pls pls answer i am waiting here...thanks for help